# What are the logistical requirements for starting a small retail company in Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland, business

If I want to start a small retailer which will import products from the far east and sell them in a small store in Switzerland, what do I need to do? I am not a resident of CH but I have the right to enter on my (US non-diplomatic) passport.

How can I rent a space if I am not a resident of the country but have right to enter as a tourist?) Are there any contracting issues for someone without residency.

Comment: This is from [this compound question](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/370/what-are-the-requirements-for-starting-a-small-retail-company-in-switzerland) to fit site requirements.

Comment: How good is your German (or French, or Italian)?

Comment: @Jonas Not good at all but enough to deal with the most basic things

Answer (score 4):

***Founding businesses is a legally regulated topic. Consult with an actual lawyer, rather than fully relying on information from the internet.***

In Switzerland, as in most countries, you cannot do business under a tourist visa (this applies even if there is a visa waiver program in place).

You therefore have two options: Either you obtain a residency and a work permit in Switzerland, and found your company that way, or you have a Swiss person found the company and  invest in their company.

The Swiss Federal Department of Economics (SECO) provides a [site for small and medium enterprises ("Kleine und Mittlere Unternehmen, KMU")](http://www.kmu.admin.ch/), with links to useful topics like [founding a company](http://www.kmu.admin.ch/kmu-gruenden/index.html?lang=de) and [import/export](http://www.kmu.admin.ch/import-export/index.html?lang=de). The sites are either in German, French, or Italian. Unless you want to make use of consulting by companies specialized in assisting founding companies (such as [this one](http://www.ansiedlung-schweiz.ch/standortvorteile-schweiz/unkomplizierte-firmengruendung/)),  I highly recommend mastering one of the three languages sufficiently well to be able to work through legal texts.

To rent a place, you will also need a residency permit that covers the duration of the contract.